# SQL Error using using XML Path Method, Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get Comma Separated String using XML Path Method

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_BankList](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [INST_ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [TITLE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ADDRESS_LINE1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CITY] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [STATE_CODE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ZIP] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LOCATION_ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ALOC] [varchar](50) NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_BankRTN](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [INST_ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [RTN] [float] NULL,
)
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT  bl.INST_ID,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + BR.[RTN]
         FROM tbl_BankRTN BR
         WHERE bl.INST_ID = BR.INST_ID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'') RTN
FROM tbl_BankList bl;
```

> Error - Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type
>   varchar to float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CAST`:

```
SELECT  bl.INST_ID,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + CAST(BR.[RTN] AS VARCHAR(1000))
         FROM tbl_BankRTN BR
         WHERE bl.INST_ID = BR.INST_ID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'') RTN
FROM tbl_BankList bl;
```

or if `SQL Server 2012+` `CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT  bl.INST_ID,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct CONCAT(',', BR.[RTN])
         FROM tbl_BankRTN BR
         WHERE bl.INST_ID = BR.INST_ID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'') RTN
FROM tbl_BankList bl;
```

**EDIT:**

To avoid scientific format wrap float with [STR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx):

> Returns character data converted from numeric data.
>
> *STR ( float_expression [ , length [ , decimal ] ] )*

```
SELECT  bl.INST_ID,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +  STR(BR.[RTN], 10,3)
         FROM tbl_BankRTN BR
         WHERE bl.INST_ID = BR.INST_ID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'') RTN
FROM tbl_BankList bl;
```

Comment: yes right, but why i am getting in this format - 1.07002e+008,1.07005e+008

Comment: @SachinPrasad Use `STR`